# How to add more padding to a field without affecting another field?

Tags: css

I'm having the following code:

```
<a class="my-profile" href="link">
  <div class="my-picture">[picture]</div>
  <div class="my-fields">
    <span class="my-name">[name]</span>
    <span class="my-medal">[medal]</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

It has the following theming:

```
.my-profile {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.my-picture {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

.my-fields {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.my-medal {
  padding-left: 5px;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
}
```

I'd like to add some more top padding to the medal field, but when I add `padding-top: 5px` to the `.my-medal` class, the name field is moved too.

Why does this happen and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set vertical alignment to the top on both the `.my-name` and `.my-medal` elements:

```css
.my-name, .my-medal {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w9Uvq/).

(Note that to show this working I've had to also specify `display: inline-block` as you haven't provided any styling for those two elements in your question).

Comment: I've updated my question and added a width and a height to the image fields `my-picture` and `my-medal`. Why isn't `vertical-align` inherited from the `my-fields` class?

Comment: Because those elements aren't inline, and `vertical-align` only affects inline content. As they're (presumably) set as blocks, they will have their own default vertical alignment (which is usually `baseline`).